# What do you call a paper that summarizes a set of mathematical formulas?

Tags: publications, publishability

A set of formulae have been collated with brief explanation for each pertaining to a statistical method called *Test of Hypothesis* from a very few set of sources. I would like to publish this work on ResearchGate. But what will I call it? It is neither research paper of novel method nor a standard survey paper. I don't suppose this is a technical report either. Yet I do believe this material would be helpful to many. What may I publish this as?

Comment: it is still a survey paper for me

Comment: I'd call it an expository paper, especially if it contains some more descriptive details on how/where to use/apply these formulas.

Comment: Cheat Sheet for Statisticians?

Comment: @santa: That's not a bad title but the matter is composed of five pages. I don't this can be called a cheat *sheet* per se. Besides, the question is not about title here.

Comment: @JaapEldering: Nice answer (although it would be better to put it in the answer section rather than commenting). So you're saying it can be still classified as an article in ResearchGate, right?

Comment: I don't know what the treshold is for calling something an "article" on researchgate, I don't use it. Furthermore, whether something like this can be considered a proper paper might differ between fields, but in my field (mathematics) expository papers do certainly exist, although they may have a slightly different status than "pure research". Still, I think a good expository paper can be very valuable.

Comment: A table of formulae?

Comment: Why not just call it a "paper"? I.e., why do you need to call it anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment turned into answer: you could call it an "expository paper", especially if it contains some more descriptive details on how/where to use/apply these formulas.

At least in my field (mathematics) such papers are not unheard of. These are often published in journals more aimed towards such papers with a broader audience, for example the [American Mathematical Monthly](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly) or [Expositiones Mathematicae](http://www.journals.elsevier.com/expositiones-mathematicae/). These papers can be of great value as a clear and easy reference to results in a particular field; on the other hand, they may not quite be considered research papers.

Comment: So I see. This means that my paper is an article nonetheless. Thank you, I have uploaded the paper in ResearchGate as an article in *Other Works* section. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you conducted a thorough evaluation/assessment/research of previous works about a specific topic and put it all together in a single document, you could call it a review paper.  If this summary cannot be found in the literature associated to your field, well, bonus points.

Comment: Sorry but review papers are reserved for experts of the field to put forward a view. I doubt my description fits that.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac not necessarily. Peer reviewed published reviews are usually done by experts, but nothing is stopping anyone from surveying the literature, comparing methods, and compiling a summarising document, that would still be a review.